# Is there a way to generate PDF in landscape orientation while accesing reports through URL?

Tags: url, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am accessing report using URL like this

```
< reportServerAddress >/ReportServer?%2f< reportName >&< parameter >=< value >&rs:Command=Render&rc:Parameters=false&rc:Toolbar=false&rs:Format=pdf
```

While in standard HTML form report is displayed properly,
in PDF format it defaults to portrait orientation (page setting are 297mm width and 210mm height).

I wasn't able to find a way to pass orientation by some parameter to the server.

Is there a way to generate report in landscape mode pdf using URLs?

I would rather not use SOAP API but will using it allow me to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The orientation is defined by the report properties. It can not be set dynamically. So you'll need to change the `Page Size`, swap the `Height` and `Width`. If you want to be able to use both orientations, you'll need two separate copies of the report.

Comment: @randomUsername did you get a chance to try this out? If it worked, please mark this as answered.

Comment: Worked For me.  I had thought I had done this already, but apparently I had not.  thanks!